# Display a list to ask user input using for loop in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, input

I have this list:

`[(1, 'Carbon'), (2, 'Nitrogen'), (3, 'Phosphorus')]`

The users will select a number that represents their choice, for example, 1 if the user wants to select Carbon.

Using and input approach, I want the user to see something like that:

```
Please select the number of your choice:


1 Carbon
2 Nitrogen
3 Phosphorus

***space for user input***
```

Then the input is saved in a variable

At the moment I am doing this by printing the list using a for loop before the input statement, but it's not enough elegant for me.

Is there a way to do this by using input and a for loop approach? Or another way to do it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [(1, 'Carbon'), (2, 'Nitrogen'), (3, 'Phosphorus')]

s ='\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in x]) for x in l])
print("Please select the number of your choice: \n\n{}".format(s))

user_input = int(input("user input : "))
```

Answer (score 0):

It did not take me too much time to see that the solution could be just to place a print statement at start simulating the input:

```
print('Select your choice')

for x in my_list:
    print(x[0],x[1])

choice = input()
```